# Mapping an Array to a Single Row

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following classes:

```
public class InventoryItem 
{ 
     private Usage[] usages = new Usage[12]; 
     virtual public Usage[] Usages { get { return usages; }} 
     virtual public string Name{get;set;} 
} 

public class Usage 
{ 
     virtual public double Quantity{get;set;} 
     virtual public string SomethingElse{get;set;} 
}
```

I know that Usages.Length will always be 12. I think it would be best 
to store it in the DB like so:

```
Name nvarchar(64), 
Usage_Quantity_0 float, 
Usage_SomethingElse_0 nvarchar(16), 
Usage_Quantity_1 float, 
Usage_SomethingElse_1 nvarchar(16), 
... 
Usage_Quantity_11 float, 
Usage_SomethingElse_11 nvarchar(16),
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

What about a getter/setter that converts to/from an array and 12 private fields? In Hibernate (I don't know about NHibernate), the mapping can be placed on the field and you can use [embeddable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e569) entities to have `Usage` be mapped to 2 columns in `InventoryItem`. If embeddable entities are not available in NHibernate, then you will need 24 fields.

A 1-to-many relationship is maybe still preferable even if there is a fixed cardinality. If you are worried about performance, search for the N+1 problem and eager fetching.

Comment: Yes, NHibernate supports the equivalent of embeddable entity, called component in this case: https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/components.html